# How to get phone files in Far Manager?

Tags: android, far-manager

When I connect my phone to Windows 10 machine I see icon with `Samsung Galaxy` phone and two folders in it - `Phone` and `Card`. When I run Far manager I don't see these directories. How to enable far manager to get access to these folders?

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use [PortaDev](https://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=933) plugin.